# Intuitive reason why bound states correspond to poles

Tags: quantum-field-theory

I've heard often that bound states correspond to poles. Why is that?

Comment: Poles *of what*? Also, I have a hard time believing that you'd keep hearing this assertion without anyone proving it. The connection of the spectral density (with delta spikes at bound states) to poles of the propagator by the [Källén-Lehmann spectral representation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/K%C3%A4ll%C3%A9n%E2%80%93Lehmann_spectral_representation) is rather standard QFT lore.

Comment: Yes, poles of the propagator/2pt correlation function. I've seen the Källén-Lehmann in Peskin I believe but am looking for a more intuitive picture.
Why does the absolute value of my Correlation function go to infinity as I approach the mass of the bound state.

Comment: I guess folks will to want to answer this question with references to S-matrix, Green's functions, and other such things. This is fine and appropriate but please note that the association between a *resonance* (a.k.a. bound state) and poles of some function is *not* just a feature of quantum mechanics. If you write the response function for an $LC$ oscillator you see precisely the same thing. A good answer might point out that the association between poles and resonances is not limited to quantum mechanics. If you attach an $LC$ resonator to transmission line you get scattering and everything.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Bound states are discrete eigenstates of the Hamiltonian $H$, hence are poles of the resolvent $(E-H)^{-1}$. In quantum mechanics, the resolvent is referred to as the Greens function or propagator, and is closely related to the T-matrix, whose poles it shares (under certain qualifications).

The poles of the S-matrix actually mean those of its matrix elements, and hence those of the T-matrix. In the relativistic case, the mass operator $M^2=p^2$ (if $c=1$) takes the role of the Hamiltonian.

Comment: There are a lot of concepts mentioned here but some more pedagogical explanation of how those concepts actually work wouldn't go amiss, I think.

Comment: @DanielSank: I wanted to answer the question, not give a course on functional analysis. All concepts I mention are well explained on Wikipedia. (The PO didn't reveal the background knowledge to be assumed, but can ask about more details if Wikipedia is not enough.)

Comment: I really don't think a course on functional analysis is needed to understand how poles are associated with resonances. Obviously nobody is going to try to twist *your* arm into writing a different answer. I'm just giving constructive feedback.

Comment: @DanielSank: A resonance is not a bound state but an idealization of a sharply peaked scattering state. The OP didn't ask about the latter. -- On the other hand, it is completely elementary that a matrix is singular (hence the inverse has a pole) whenever there is a singular eigenvalue.

Comment: Alright, this helps. Could we iterate it? Eg choose a Hamiltonian different from the mass operator such that the first bound state is feeling the potential of another source? Or is even part of a bigger bound state?

Comment: @tonydo: The Hamiltonian (or, in the relativistic case, the mass operator) determines (through its form) all interactions and (through its spectrum) all bound states. One cannot choose different interactions (or external potentials) for different bound states.