# Why does S-matrix have poles?

Tags: quantum-field-theory, singularities, s-matrix-theory, unitarity

Why does unitarity require amplitudes to have singularities? I can see this by constructing amplitudes for specific processes, but what is the rationale behind the general rule? For concreteness, consider a $2\to2$ amplitude $A(s,t)$-why must it have an $s$ channel pole at $m^2$ (it is perhaps relevant that $s=m^2$ would be the kinematical requirement to *just* produce 1 particle from 2)? I can obviously note that the leading tree level $2\to 2$ amplitude will just go as $1/(s-m^2)$ and thus the pole, but I do not wish to invoke perturbation theory. I wish to understand, *can we infer that the amplitudes must have singularities, just from unitarity? If so, how?*.

I suspect this has something to do with the optical theorem (specifically, the fact that the propagator becomes imaginary on-shell), but I cannot make a precise connection.

Comment: Possible duplicate: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/212559/50583